# Python Numpy Matrix Operations - matrix[a==b]?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matrix

I've been trying to create a watershed algorithm and as all the examples seem to be in Python I've run into a bit of a wall. I've been trying to find in numpy documentation what this line means:

```
matrixVariable[A==255] = 0
```

but have had no luck. Could anyone explain what that operation does?

For context the line in action: [`label [lbl == -1] = 0`](https://github.com/thegreatshasha/dopencv/blob/master/theone.py)

Comment: [This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `A == 255` creates a boolean array which is `True` where x == 255 in A and `False` otherwise.

The expression `matrixVariable[A==255] = 0` sets each index corresponding to a `True` value in A == 255 to 0.

EG:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
B = np.zeros([3, 3])
print('before:')
print(B)
B[A>5] = 5
print('after:')
print(B)
```

OUT:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
after:
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  5.]
 [ 5.  5.  5.]]
```

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with numpy in the future. This talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEUXKG97YRw is a great way to get more fluent with numpy if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that matrixVariable and A are numpy arrays. If the assumption is correct then "matrixVariable[A==255] = 0" expression first gets the index of the array A where values of A are equal to 255 then gets the values of matrixVariable for those index and set them to "0"

Example:

```
import numpy as np

matrixVariable = np.array([(1, 3),
                           (2, 2),
                           (3,1)])

A = np.array([255, 1,255])
```

So A[0] and A[2] are equal to 255

```
matrixVariable[A==255]=0 #then sets matrixVariable[0] and matrixVariable[2] to zero

print(matrixVariable) # this would print 

[[0 0] 
 [2 2] 
 [0 0]]
```